# Databricks pyspark indexing data into Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pyspark, databricks

Trying to index data into elasticsearch from databricks using pyspark.  It works with the same configuration and scala, but when trying to write to ES using pyspark it fails (Needed based on some transforms using python packages).

```
esconf = {}
esconf['es.nodes.wan.only'] = 'true'
esconf['es.port'] = '9999'
esconf['es.net.ssl'] = 'true'
esconf['es.read.metadata'] = 'true'
esconf['es.nodes'] = esURL
esconf['ex.index.auto.create'] = 'true'
esconf['es.resource.auto.create'] = 'geohashing/testing'

geoCordsSchema.write.format('org.elasticsearch.spark.sql').options(**esconf).mode('Overwrite').save('geohash/test')
```

Error Produced:
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'

Any ideas/suggestions what I'm missing and why this config would work with scala but not using pyspark?

Comment: hi did you find a solution for this, am working on a poc, to write data from databricks to elasticsearch.  Can you please provide some sample code or reference please.

Comment: I was able to make this work with using the python "elasticsearch" package, and helpers.parallel_bulk().